# Stored Procedure para crear usuario en MySQL

Tags: mysql

¡Hola!. Estoy creando un Stored Procedure para crear un usuario en MySQL.

Le asigno al usuario el valor de 'Luis' y contraseña '1234' y al ejecutar el Stored Procedure me crea un usuario pero con el nombre 'Usuario' en lugar de tomar el valor que le asigno como parámetro 'Luis'
¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

```
-- Crear procedimiento almacenado para insertar usuarios
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Crear_Usuario (IN usuario varchar (10), IN pass varchar (10))
BEGIN
    CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS usuario@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY pass;
END
//
DELIMITER;
```

De esta manera ejecuto mi Stored Procedure

```
-- Ejecución del Stored Procedure
call Crear_Usuario('Luis', '12345')
```

Comment: Saludos. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes que concatenar tus variables para que el Statement/query sea correcto , como este.

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'Luis'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '12345'
```

En tu caso el valor de tus variables le faltan comillas, hay varias formas de ponerlas y ejecutar el query correcto.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE Crear_Usuario(IN usuario varchar (10), IN passe varchar (10))
BEGIN
    /* Concatenamos el query con las variables y comillas*/
    SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS ', "'", usuario, "'", "@'localhost'", ' IDENTIFIED BY ', "'" , passe , "'" );

    /* descomenta esta linea para ver el query generado
    select @sql; 
    */

    /* se ejecuta el query */
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql; 
    EXECUTE stmt1; 
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

END //

DELIMITER ;

call Crear_Usuario('Luis','12345')
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, justo lo que necesitaba. Es una buena práctica la que me comentas, concatenar la instrucción en una sola variable, ya que el código lo estaba tomando literal con la cadena usuario, y no su contenido. ¡Saludos!

Comment: y para darle permisos como select o update como le hace, ese es mi duda.